# scp to EC2 failing because of permission error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp

I'm trying to scp a project onto my EC2 instance. I have my .pem keys but the scp seems not to be able to find my keys, despite giving it the full address. Any insights?

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-19-174 ~]$ scp -i /Users/.../my_keys.pem -r /Users/.../project ec2-user@....us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:~/

Warning: Identity file /Users/.../my_keys.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
lost connection
```

Btw, I can ssh into the instance with

```
ssh -i /Users/.../my_keys.pem ec2-user@ec2-user@....us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

(albeit with the following warning)

```
The authenticity of host '[host_name]' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is [fingerprint_name].
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Comment: The error is saying it can't find/access your `my_keys.pem` file. Can you `ssh` into the instance using the same key file?

Comment: @John Rotenstein Yes, edited

Comment: Similar: [amazon ec2 - Why getting a permission denied (public key) error for SCP when SSH works - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/293949/why-getting-a-permission-denied-public-key-error-for-scp-when-ssh-works)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to scp content from your local pc into an AWS instance?
If you are it looks like you are running your scp from your ec2 instance and not your local:

`[ec2-user@ip-172-31-19-174 ~]$ scp -i /Users/.../my_keys.pem -r /Users/.../project ec2-user@....us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:~/`

Note the start of your line: **[ec2-user@ip-172-31-19-174 ~]**

You should be doing the scp from your local machine, if that's what you're trying to achieve.

In short, you're already ssh'd onto the server.